# Web Tab Opening a new tab in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-experience, salesforce-classic, web-tab

I have created a web tab that opens the link of the desired url , in classic experience, the tab is opened in the same tab, but in lightning it is opening a new browser tab, how can i prevent this from the happening in lightning experience ?

Comment: This behavior sounds to me as though it is working as designed. Things in Lightning work differently than in Classic. Lightning generally opens a new tab rather than reusing the same one.

Comment: @crmprogdev by new tab you mean "browser tab" , yes ?

Comment: Yes the Browser is what I was referring to. Were you referring to a different tab?